# Tabbing between jquery EditInPlace fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with a bunch of jquery EditInPlace tags and the client would like to allow the user to tab between fields (i.e. tabbing would launch the next .eip field.  Is this even possible? I'm using the 'jquery-in-place-editor' located here: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-in-place-editor/

The code is currently behind a login screen, so it's hard for me to show it.  At this point I'm mostly interested in how one would go about doing this - I'm pretty new to jQuery, so I don't think I have the current skills to do this one, but it seems like one should be able to catch the tab (through the blur() function?) and then call the click() function on the next .eip element.  But that's about as far as my understanding goes...  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you use paragraph-tags to hold your data, as does the demo.

Then you need to set the tabIndex of all your .eip-fields because otherwise they won't recieve focus when you tab between you html-elements.

Having set the tabIndex you should be able to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.eip').focus(function(){$(this).click();});
});
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I've set tabindex on all the .eip fields (actually I could do this in jQuery) but I didn't know if tabindex works on spans (what I'm using for the EIP fields.  I'll give your code a shot, hopefully it's just that simple - thanks!

Comment: You should be able to give focus to a span by giving it a tabIndex greater than zero.

Comment: Did you succed in giving your spans focus?